# Forming clans in clash of clans

Tags: clash-of-clans

This is my first day in clash of clans and I have heard a lot about clans some people say join my clan some say the F word what is a clan and how to join or make one.

Comment: If you want upvotes, put some more effort into your questions.  Punctuation, for one.  Single run on sentences do not show any effort.  Generally, upvotes are given for *effort*.  This question shows none.

Comment: @Frank As well as the fact that you should try to find the answer to your question elsewhere (Google) first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A Clan is a group of people that form together to provide troops to each other (to help defend your base or use them in attacks) and to fight wars against other clans.  You will also have a separate chat just for your clan and will be eligible to complete clan related achievements (donations, etc).

**You must have a clan castle built before you can be in a clan**.  To build one, you must repair your clan castle and this will cost 40,000 gold.   Your ruined clan castle will already be on your screen and look like this:

[image]

If you post in chat that you are looking for a clan, most recruiters will just send you an invite that you can accept or decline in your inbox.  This is the letter icon right about the attack button on your home screen.   Otherwise you can start a clan by clicking on your clan castle and selecting create clan.  This will cost you 40,000 gold.

[From Clash of Clan's Wiki Site:](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clans)

> Clans are groups of players that pool their Trophies to compete with other clans to have the most Trophies. Members of clans have a private chat for socializing with each other and are able to donate troops to each other. Within a clan there are four ranks, member, elder, co-leader, and leader. Including the leader, you can have up to 50 members in a clan.

You can get more information on clans on the link posted above and [more information on clan castles here.](http://clashofclans.wikia.com/wiki/Clan_Castle)